# How to track exact position of processed rows so as to resume upon 'connection already closed' problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am doing a datasets transfer between two databases on different postgres servers. The process would take couple of weeks because of large records in source database. However, the source database closes the connection after like 9-11days, so the transfer halt, I  therefore need a way to continue from last operation when restarted.

Currently, I have written a script (python) that does the transfer. So I use a terminal multiplexer (screen) to have it running on the VM. But then after say a week, the source database server closes the connection so the process stop, (no problem with screen session, still alive).

In my script I make it in a way that the resultset (in json) is displayed and then transferred, so that I am sure process is on-going. But when the source db server closes the connection (so no resultset get fetched again), and  all I get is the `connection already closed` message.

Please see my python script below (I'm quite new to python).

My objective here is implement a way of continuation from the previously processed row onward after the `connection already closed` problem occurred.

```
    db = "select to_json(d) from (  select \
        n.noise_data as measurand, \
        n.factor as \"sonometerClass\", \
        to_timestamp(n.seconds) as \"dateObserved\", \
        l.description as name, \
            json_build_object( \
                'coordinates', \
                json_build_array(l.node_lon, l.node_lat) \
            ) as location \
        from noise as n \
            inner join deployment as d on \
                d.deployment_id = n.deployment_id \
            inner join location as l on \
                l.location_id = d.location_id \
       ORDER BY n.seconds ASC \
    ) as d"
    return db

def main():

    conn = None
    try:
        params = config()
        with psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
            with conn.cursor(name='m_cursor') as cur:
                cur.itersize = 1000
                cur.execute(val_json())

                for row in tqdm(cur):
                    jData = json.dumps(row)
                    print(jData)

                   # do transfer stuff here...
                     ...
                    sleep(2)

                cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: With no ORDER BY in the query, I don't think it would be possible to start where you left off. Why not use postgres_fdw to transfer the data instead of running this through python?

Comment: @Jeremy I am passing the resultset to an application the accept json and creates it own schema. I dont understand why you mention the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: How can you continue from the previously processed row if the rows are not ordered?  The next time you run the query, the rows could be in a completely different order.

Comment: @Jeremy I edit my query (so also in question above) so rows are ordered in ascending order of `seconds` column in table `noise`